# Check if a total order refines a partial order

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

Consider pairs (x,y) of integers. We impose a partial order such that (x,y) ≤ (x',y') wrt. that partial order of x ≤ x' and y ≤ y'. If neither (x,y) ≤ (x',y') nor (x',y') ≤ (x,y), we say that (x,y) and (x',y') are incomparable.

Now, I have a list `ls` of such pairs. I want to check that the order of that list refines the partial order defined above; i.e., I need to check that to the right of any element in the list, there come no smaller elements.

Of course I could do the following:

```
def leq_po(u,v):
    return all(a <= b for a, b in zip(u,v))
def le_po(u,v):
    return leq_po(u,v) and u != v
def list_refines_po(ls):
    return all(not le_po(ls[j], ls[i]) 
               for i in range(len(ls)) for j in range(i+1, len(ls)))
```

However, then gives me some kind of O(n²)-complexity, while checking that a list is sorted wrt. total order takes O(n)-time.

Now, probably, that's what I've got to expect: partial orders generalise total orders, so probably, I should expect that checking the more general notion has a worse complexity. But:

Can I do better than O(n²)?

**Edit**
To try, you can use the following data:

```
ls_in_order     = [(0, 1), (2, 1), (3, 0), (2, 1)]
ls_not_in_order = [(0, 1), (2, 1), (3, 0), (1, 1)]
```

Here, no pair of consecutive entries in `ls_not_in_order` is descending, but the list is not in order (because `(2,1) ≥ (1,1)`).

Comment: Could you show an example `ls` that *isn't* simply sorted in ascending order?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Added.

Comment: Maybe using some sort of TreeMap: Create two search trees (like TreeMap in Java), one sorted by first element, the other sorted by second element. Iterate the elements and add them to the trees; get the sets of elements greater-or-equal to the first and the second element from those two trees, get their intersection, and see if any of those elements are strictly greater than your current element. Probably still O(n²), but might be faster in practice.

Comment: For questions that are simply looking for an algorithm rather than help with the implementation code, you might also consider https://cs.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Kahn's algorithm](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/topological-sorting-indegree-based-solution/) to sort the partial order, at every step trying to choose what is next in the total order.  If you succeed, then the total order refines the partial order.  If you fail, then it does not.

The time will be `O(v + e)` where `v` is the number of vertices, and `e` is the number of directed edges that define the partial order.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in `O(n log n)` time using a [balanced BST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree), plus an auxiliary doubly linked list of predecessors/successors for that BST.

The idea is to iterate through the points in the total order, maintaining a data structure that can tell you in `log n` time whether we've seen a point whose x and y values are at least as large as our current point. We'll keep an ordered sequence of points `(p1, p2, ... pk)` whose x-values are increasing and y-values are decreasing, forming a kind of diagonal down-and-right stepped line. To add a point `P = (x,y)` (ignoring ties for now), do a binary search based on x, and insert P into the BST and into the linked list so that x-values are still increasing.

If you let P.left and P.right denote the predecessor and successor of point P in our sequence, we can check whether P caused an order violation by testing whether P.right.y >= P.y: If so, because P.right has a higher-or-equal x-value and higher-or-equal y-value, this violates the partial order (again, ignoring exact ties for now). Otherwise, to maintain the decreasing order of y-values, we repeatedly delete P.left from the tree and our list as long as P.left.y <= P.y. In total, this takes `n log n` time, since we ultimately perform at most one search, insertion, or deletion on every node, but some steps may take longer than others.

To deal with tied values of x, if the value of y is tied as well, we only check for partial order violations, and don't change the tree or list (and don't insert a copy of P). If the value of P.y is smaller than the old point's y, there is a violation. Otherwise, delete the old point and check for violations/update the tree like normal.